# Creating a docker image for training a deep learning model

Tags: python, docker, deep-learning

currently I have a deep learning model that I am able to train with environments and packages managed by Anaconda. I'm looking at how can I package all the dependency  along with my code into a docker container.

One approach that I thought of was to execute `pip freeze` to get the package versions in my environment put them into a `requirements.txt` and then use that to run the `pip install -r requirements.txt`. Would this be the best way to go about this?

Could someone provide me with some pointers to get started on this, I am not very familiar with Docker hence request answers to provide simple explainations and refer resources wherever possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python","file.py"]
```